# Show custom fields on the collection page in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am using a plugin that filters products. This means that products are no longer shown in the traditional product loop. I think the plugin has switched to using javascript to show products on the collection page rather than liquid.

For every product on a collection page, I wish to show its colour. Each product has a colour associated with it using a custom field.

If I manually manually enter a product handle in the below code, the colour for the product handle that has been entered successfully displays for each product.

```
{{ all_products["MANUALLY ENTERED PRODUCT HANDLE"].metafields.custom_fields["colour"] }}
```

I am also able to dynamically able to get a products handle with `{!productHandle!}`

For some reason however when I put the two together like this:

```
  {{ all_products["{!productHandle!}"].metafields.custom_fields["colour"] }}
```

The result is that nothing is shown.

My question is, how can I dynamically pull the product handle into the custom field? I have already tried

```
{{ all_products[product.handle].metafields.custom_fields["colour"] }}
```

and

```
{{ all_products[product-handle].metafields.custom_fields["colour"] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the handle as a string. Eg:

```
{% capture fizz %}{{product.handle}}{%endcapture%}
{{ all_products[fizz].metafields.custom_fields["colour"] }}
```

Note that all_products is also limited to just 20 products.